# Detached entity passed to persist while using embedded class in entity

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

As, I am reading the JPA (Java Persistence API). There I read about the Embeddable Classes. So, I am trying to use that concept in my entity class. But while using this I am facing a problem of detached entity.

Here I have Embeddable Class(ZipCode) in Entity.

**Embeddable Class**

```
@Embeddable public class ZipCode {    
private String zip;    
private String plusFour; 

//getter & setter also.
}
```

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Embedded
private ZipCode zipCode;

//getter & setter also.

}
```

**My persistence Code:**

```
@WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private CrudService crudService;

public RegisterServlet() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ZipCode z = new ZipCode();
    z.setZip("bharti");
    z.setPlusFour("rawat");

    Address a = new Address();
    a.setId(1);
    a.setZipCode(z);

    try{
        crudService.create(a);

    }catch(Exception e){
        log.info("exception occurs "+ e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

**My CrudSrvice Code**:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class CrudServiceImpl implements CrudService {   
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "localmedecube")
private EntityManager em;

public CrudServiceImpl() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public <T> T create(T t) {
    this.em.persist(t);
    this.em.flush();
    this.em.refresh(t);
    return t;
}

@Override
public void delete(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class type, Object id) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Object ref = this.em.getReference(type, id);
    this.em.remove(ref);

}

@Override
public <T> T update(T t) {
    return this.em.merge(t);
}
```

}

When I try to persist my Address entity it is giving me error like this

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: model.Address

Please tell me why this exception is comes. Also provide me appropriate answer for it.

Comment: how do you try to persist it. Can you share crudService.create method

Comment: Ok @xxlali i shared CRUD code also.

Comment: hmm, you use persist method. As I know, you should not set id of an object if you use persist method. Please try it again by removing `a.setId(1);`

Comment: post your table definition ... column names and types. You set IDENTITY strategy so you should have "AUTO_INCREMENT" or something similar for the column type of "id"

Comment: By removing the a.setId(1) it will 100% will persist the data in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have persisted an `Address` with `id = 1` then your code breaks. You have to set on each request a new `id`.

Since you use already

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private long id;
```

the database should set the id for you. Prerequisites for this is that the field `id` was created as an auto-increment field.

For example setting an auto-increment field at creation in `MySQL`.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
<...>
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: you are right. By removing a.setId(1) code will work fine.